# LibGDX - Activate accelerometer in runtime

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an application which uses the accelerometer, but only occasionally under rare circumstances. I'd like to preserve battery by having it disabled by default and only turn it on when needed.

Only thing I've found is setting configurations when initializing the app from [this site](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Configuration-&-querying)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useCompass = false;
    config.useAccelerometer = false;

    MyGame myGame = new MyGame(new AndroidPlatform(this, config));

    initialize(myGame , config);
}
```

But I can't find a way to enable/disable it while the app is running. Anyone have an idea?

EDIT:

In the above example AndroidPlatform is implementing a Platform interface in the core project. I tried out Zoe's idea of passing the config to platform implementation and changing it follows:

```
@Override
public void enableAccelerometer(boolean enable) {
    config.useCompass = enable;
    config.useAccelerometer = enable;
}
```

and then in the core project when the accelerometer should be enabled:

```
private void startInclineMonitoring() {
        System.out.println("Before:");
        System.out.println(Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer));
        System.out.println(Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Compass));

        platform.enableAccelerometer(true);

        System.out.println("After:");
        System.out.println(Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer));
        System.out.println(Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Compass));
}
```

Unfortunately this outputs:

```
I/System.out: Before:
I/System.out: false
I/System.out: false
I/System.out: After:
I/System.out: false
I/System.out: false
```

So, no luck there.

Comment: You could pass it as a parameter to the constructor and try to enable it through the instance, but I'm not sure if it'll work or not

Comment: Do you mean pass the config as a parameter to the application constructor? Could give it a go

Comment: Pass it to the core project. If the AndroidConfig class isn't available, create a wrapper class in the android project with an interface or abstract class in the core project

Comment: Tried it (see above edits), but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's no easy way to do this as of today, but I ended up doing my own (Android) motion sensor implementation. I thought I'd share it for future visitors:

This assumes you have your platform interface and platform specific implementation as explained in [this wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

First these methods are added to the interface:

```
public interface Platform {
    public void startMotionSensors(PlatformCallback<float[]> callback);

    public void stopMotionSensors();
}
```

And in the android implementation:

```
public class AndroidPlatform implements Platform {

    private Activity activity;
    private MotionSensor motionSensor;
    private Handler handler;

    public AndroidPlatform(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.motionSensor = new MotionSensor(activity);
        this.handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void startMotionSensors(final PlatformCallback<float[]> callback) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                motionSensor.start(callback);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stopMotionSensors() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                motionSensor.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The MotionSensor class:

```
public class MotionSensor implements SensorEventListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    private float[] gravity = new float[3];
    private float[] geomag = new float[3];

    private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] inclinationMatrix = new float[16];

    private PlatformCallback<float[]> callback;

    public MotionSensor(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                gravity = event.values.clone();
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                geomag = event.values.clone();
                break;
        }

        if (gravity != null && geomag != null) {
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix,
                    inclinationMatrix, gravity, geomag);

            if (success) {
                notifyCallback(new Result(), rotationMatrix);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    private void notifyCallback(Result result, float[] rotationMatrix) {
        callback.callback(result, rotationMatrix);
    }

    public void start(PlatformCallback<float[]> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (sensorManager != null) {
            boolean accelerometerSupport = sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
            boolean magneticFieldSupport = sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

            if (!accelerometerSupport || !magneticFieldSupport) {
                sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                notifyCallback(new Result(Result.STATE.FAILED, "Not supported"), null);
            }
        } else {
            notifyCallback(new Result(Result.STATE.FAILED, "Not supported"), null);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (sensorManager != null) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And the PlaformCallback class:

```
public abstract class PlatformCallback<T> {

    public void callback(final Result result, final T t) {
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doCallback(result, t);
            }
        });
    }

    protected abstract void doCallback(Result result, T t);
}
```

In the core project you can now simply turn on and off your motion sensors:

```
private void startMotionSensor() {
    platform.startMotionSensors(new PlatformCallback<float[]>() {
        @Override
        protected void doCallback(Result result, float[] rotationMatrix) {
            if (result.ok()) {
                // Do what you want with the rotation matrix
            }
        }
    });
}

public void stopMotionSensor() {
    platform.stopMotionSensors();
}
```